# Как сделать SSL аутентификацию Oracle?

Tags: oracle, ssl, domain

Пытаюсь настроить SSL_аутентификацию в своей локальной по [этой инструкции](https://www.trustwave.com/en-us/resources/blogs/spiderlabs-blog/how-to-setting-up-encrypted-communications-channels-in-oracle-database/). На этапе `orapki wallet add -wallet /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/db_wallet -dn 'CN=root_test_CA,C=US' -keysize 2048 -self_signed -validity 10 -pwd MYPSWD`. Конструкция **-dn 'CN=root_test_CA,C=US'** требует доменного имени вместо root_test_CA. Могу ли я на windows server 2008 настроить Active Directory в своей локальной сети и использовать этот домен? Или требуется сделать по-другому?

Comment: А почему  просто не указать доменное имя сервера БД?

Comment: @0xdb спасибо, попробую

Comment: не вышло. Я установил базу на windows server 2008 r2, настроил active directory, домен.  Команда не принимает доменное имя

Comment: Делайте воспроизводимый пример - где и какие команды выполняете, на какой версии итд. Просто добавить самоподписанный сертификат, попробовал, выполняется без ошибок, причём с произвольным CN.